# Command line runner for Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

Is there a way to use Micronaut to create a command line application? I mean something similar to Spring Boot command line runner as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app

There are still a lot of Micronaut features that are relevant to not just a server application but also a command line application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use Micronaut to create a command line application?

Yes.  You can create a command line app using the `create-cli-app` command.

```
mn create-cli-app my-cli-app
```

See https://docs.micronaut.io/1.0.4/guide/index.html#commandLineApps for more information.

I hope that helps.